# Background-size: 100% not working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, responsive-design, mobile-safari, css

I can't figure out why the background-size: 100% 100% is working in the Safari browser on my desktop and in all the iphone emulators online, but not on an actual iPhone.

The URL of the site is http://cherrycompanies.com

The CSS I'm using is

```
#header {
background: url(images/header.png) no-repeat top left;
background-size: 100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
margin: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you replace `background-size: 100% 100%` with `background-size: contain` ?

Comment: Ok I have it set to contain now, but it still doesn't work on the phone :(